# CakePHP 3 - table join through other?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to create the following DB structure:

[image]

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/generic_pos/index.htm

Specifically, i am looking at the relationship between:

- `sales_transaction`
- `products`
- `products_in_transaction`

I want the relationship setup, so that i can make calls to the `sales_transaction` DB and then just contain the `products`, and it fetches everything in 1 query.
However, it just aint working, so please help me out :-)

Here is my code:

**SalesTransactionTable**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

    $this->hasMany('Products', [
        'through' => 'ProductsInTransaction'
    ]);
}
```

**ProductsTable**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

    $this->belongsToMany('SalesTransaction', [
        'through' => 'ProductsInTransaction'
    ]);
}
```

**ProductsInTransactionTable**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

    $this->belongsTo('SalesTransaction', [
        'foreignKey' => 'transaction_id',
        'joinType' => 'inner'
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'joinType' => 'inner'
    ]);
}
```

The relationship should be obvious from the above statement. In essence, `SalesTransaction` contains all my transactions, and the `products_in_transaction` is my join-table to bridge it together with `products`, but just look at the link to get the full scheme.

When i try to run this code to fetch it:

```
$sales_transactions = $sales_transactions_table->find('all', [
            'conditions' => [
                'device_id IN' => $deviceIdsInDepartment
            ],
            'contain' => [
                'Products'
            ]
        ]);
```

i get this error:
[image: error]

Comment: "it just aint working" really tells us nothing. What is the problem you're having? There is no question here.

Comment: i just need to make sure the relationship is set up right in cake as compared to the statement. i will add some more, 2 sec

Comment: added more info

Comment: You need to define the primary keys for your tables since you're using a non-cake convention for column names.

Comment: don' t think that is the problem - the issue is, that it tries to get products by looking directly at the products table, but it should first go through the joining table (ProductsInTransaction) but even though i said it belongs through that table it doesn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a `hasMany` association in your `SalesTransaction` model.

It should be a `belongsToMany`:

**SalesTransactionTable**

```
$this->belongsToMany('Products', [
    'through' => 'ProductsInTransaction'
]);
```